# PHP input filtering : Only English alphabet

Tags: php

What is the best way for check the input, if it contains any character from other languages. (except english )

Comment: What precisely do you mean by characters from other languages? Are you wanting to exclude é for example which although often dropped in anglicised words is used in English all the time.

Comment: This question seems a little naïve

Comment: "Are you wanting to exclude é for example which although often dropped in anglicised words is used in English all the time"
yes

Comment: This is a very bad idea. You should *embrace* other languages through [internationalization and localization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization), not filter them out.

Comment: @Randolpho , how can google detect a language in translate page?

Comment: @phpExe: is *that* what you're trying to do? Google does it by having a **very** extensive database of words and phrases that are keyed to a particular language. "Aller" is French, "Gehen" is German, "To Go" is English, etc. If a page was indexed as having a significant number of words in a particular language, it offers to translate for you.

Comment: @Randolpho, No, Im only curious about google. Your answer is that Im trying to do. Thanks for help and answer.

Comment: @phpExe: Google probably has some sort of neural network running. It should detect the language by counting the what letters appear next to other letters.

Comment: @Alix Axel: I think it's far more likely that they detect language based on words and phrases than individual letters.

Comment: @Randolpho: No, not individual letters, combinations of letters. An example: the combination `ph` is much more likely to appear more times in English than in Portuguese. They do this, not just to two letter combinations but combinations of n letters.

Comment: @Alix Axel: that seems overly complex when a simpler solution would be a lexical database that maps words to languages and a simple count of words' languages during the indexing of the page. They have both the computing power and the storage space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("/[^\x00-\x7F]/",$string)) {
  // $string contains at least 
} else {
  // $string doesn't contain any foreign characters
}
```

This will check for any character that has ascii code higher than 127, because if it is higher, it's not in the english alphabet. The 7-bit Ascii code contains every english character.

[image: Ascii Table]
[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20100706220519/http://www.cs.utk.edu:80/~pham/ascii.html)

Answer (score 2):

if this

```
preg_match("/[^\x00-\x7F]/",$string)
```

doesn't work *(you get No ending delimiter '/' found )* then try this

```
preg_match('/[^\x00-\x7F]/',$string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = 'abcабв';
$out = array();
preg_match_all(
    "|[a-zA-Z]?|",
    $input,
    $out
);
```

$out is going to contain all non-latin characters(абв).

Comment: and what about special chars like `.`, `()`, `[]` or so much more that can be in a string without making it a string in foreign language?